# Configuration for Amazon S3 bucket for thumbnail in Amazon Elastic transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm having a problem inputting bucket location in Creating pipeline on Elastic transcoder!

[image]

The Error is

> Error 1 validation error detected: Value
>   'http://www.videostest.com/thumb' at 'thumbnailConfig.bucket' failed
>   to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern:
>   ^(\w|.|-){1,255}$

I don't know what the problem is. I'm sure I'm putting the right file location.
Could anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the CNAME attached for the bucket or your app [ I guess you have configured CNAME for the S3 and so you are entering that ].

You need to put the S3 Bucket Name. Actually you need not even type the S3 Bucket name, you place the cursor in the text box, it auto fills. If you are not getting the auto suggestion, chances are you do not have a S3 Bucket created in that region.

It isn't that hard / complicated. Also check if your IAM user account has access to the S3.

[image]

Comment: Actually I need to put thumbnail location on folder named "thumb" and the folder is in s3 bucket!!